# Why i can't installing pyaudio?

Tags: python

This statement error always pop up after doing pip install pyaudio, what does it mean? did my PC didn't supported for installing pyaudio? (btw, this is mu first to posting a question in stackoverflow) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFZIQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't u use `pip install pyaudio` instead of the full name?
This could be caused by an out of date pip version. Update pip and try again.

Comment: i use to follow tutorial from youtube, but now i already successfully installing pyaudio. thank you for you answer anyway.